# Why won't my flames render when rendering or on viewport (2.8)

Tags: fire

I'm making an animation with the sun having flares then collapsing causing a supernova followed by a black hole, however after baking the fire for hours I get nothing on the viewport or the render. I'm going to edit in the blender file.

Edit: Blender File https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/85qjL5NR

Comment: Please don't make the question depend exclusively on users downloading the file and spending time  reverse engineering what you did. Add images as part of your post that show the current settings for the emitter and the smoke domain, and show the nodes for the materials used on the smoke domain.